# Adding ViewModel Select List to IEnumerable view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have the contents of my select list stored in a ViewModel and I would like to display the select list on a IEnumerable page.

The error I'm receiving is "CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'QualifiedList' and no extension method 'QualifiedList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea how to reference the select list in an IEnumerable View?

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MEOregistration.Models.MEOmodel>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Status, Model.QualifiedList)
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace MEOregistration.Models
{
    public class MEOmodel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> QualifiedList
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "Pending Qualficiation", Text = "Pending Qualification" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "Dis-Qualified", Text = "Dis-Qualified" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "Qualified", Text = "Qualified" }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you have @model [modelThatContainsQualifiedList] at the top?

Comment: What `type` is your view model?

Comment: i have tested your code it is working can you show your action and view

Comment: I updated my code to provide more clarity

Comment: And the down vote is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference the the member that way. You need to change your model type to `@model MEOregistration.Models.MEOmodel`

Or use a partial `meo.cshtml`:

```
@model MEOregistration.Models.MEOmodel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Status, Model.QualifiedList)
```

Called by

```
@foreach(var meo in Model)
{
  @Html.Partial("partial",meo)
}
```